# Pay later payment method does not get overwritten when payment is made

Tags: civicontribute

When someone selects Pay Later, the payment method defaults to Cheque.

When they pay, we record the payment method they used, for example, Bank Transfer.

When I do a search on contributions made by Bank Transfer I get no results, because the original payment method of Cheque persists on the record.

Is this a bug?

WHat I want to happen is that the original payment method of cheque is overridden by the actual payment method used when payment was finally made.

[image: Screenshot of contribution record]

Comment: perhaps a sub-question is - if someone selects PayLater why is 'any' payment method set since we don't know, and/or why isn't there an 'unknown' option :-)